# What is wrong with this code attempting to concatenate strings in C?

Tags: c, gdb, concatenation

I am just attempting to concatenate two strings in C and I don't know why but I'm getting segfault errors.  I tracked it down using gdb to the first line in the lines of code below.

```
  strcat(tempString, "uptime");
  pFile = fopen (tempString,"r");
```

tempString is = "/proc/".  I just want to append the string "uptime" to the tempString and then attempt to open the file if it exists in the /proc folder.  When memcpy() is called by strcat() is when the actual segfault occurs.

Comment: Did you allocate `tempString` correctly?

Comment: Originally no, but now I switched it over to char tempString[80] and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have not shown some code before these lines, but it is likely tempString is assigned using

```
tempString = "/proc/";
```

Which makes it a constant (with constant mem size allocation)
The 2nd line `strcat` will atempt to overwrite the string constant, which puts 6 bytes beyond your buffer into unknown territory (*if it succeeded).

Use strcat responsibly: http://beej.us/guide/bgc/output/html/multipage/strcat.html

* as JeremyP points out, if it points to the text segment, it is read only and will cause the segfault

Comment: Actually, if your assumption about the declaration is correct (I'm sure it is), then tempString points to a location in the text segment, which is likely to be read only.  That is probably the cause of the seg fault.

Comment: That is what I did, so I changed it to do a strcpy(tempString,"/proc/") and it is still doing the same thing.

Comment: @nmr: You're probably not allocating space for the string.  Try something like `char tempString[128];` (the size you need may vary).

Comment: Thank you for the helpful link.  I will definitely be more mindful in the future.

Answer (score 2):

It would help confirm things if you showed us the line that defines `tempString`.  However, it looks like you've got something like `char * tempString = "/proc/";`, and are trying to modify that.  Since it's a quoted string, you may or may not be able to modify it, and a segmentation fault is quite likely if you try.  (Moreover, `"/proc/"` is seven `char` long, and adding anything to the end would overwrite something or other.)

For a modifiable string, you need to have your own buffer, allocated either on the stack or on the heap, and you need to make sure it's long enough.

Comment: I count 6 chars in "/proc/" but the day is early for me so I may be wrong.

Comment: so could I just explicitly allocate an array to handle the space issue?  Or do I have to use malloc()?

Comment: @nmr You can use `malloc()`, but allocating on the stack (`char tempString[1024]`) should be easier for you.

Comment: @cyberkiwi: 6 characters plus 1 null terminator = 7 char required.